# Jupyter Notebook Import Error when importing nbinteract

Tags: jupyter

I am importing libraries inside jupyter notebook, when I face an awkward error. Could you please tell me how I could fix it?
It seems the problem has something to do with the system, and I am using a M1-MacBook.
Here is the import:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import nbinteract as nbi

sns.set()
sns.set_context('talk')
np.set_printoptions(threshold=20, precision=2, suppress=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 7)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 8)
pd.set_option('precision', 2)
# This option stops scientific notation for pandas
# pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/h3/kst79dg57g18qj470505fpq40000gn/T/ipykernel_6876/3125672849.py in ()
     14 import ipywidgets as widgets
     15 from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
---> 16 import nbinteract as nbi
     17 
     18 sns.set()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nbinteract/__init__.py in 
     10 warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message="numpy.ufunc size changed")
     11 
---> 12 from .exporters import *
     13 from .plotting import *
     14 from .questions import *

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nbinteract/exporters.py in 
     24 from IPython.display import display, Javascript, Markdown
     25 
---> 26 from nbconvert import HTMLExporter
     27 from traitlets import default, Unicode, Bool, validate, TraitError
     28 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/nbconvert/__init__.py in 
      2 
...
---> 19 from base64 import encodestring
     20 from .rwbase import NotebookReader, NotebookWriter
     21 from .nbbase import from_dict

ImportError: cannot import name 'encodestring' from 'base64' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/base64.py)
```

Try to fix the problem.

Comment: Looks a similar issue is cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-does-not-work/19841?u=fomightez). Please always link all cross-posts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue of nbinteract because it doesnot have support with latest python version, as you are using **pyhton 3.11** which is quite latest.

You can go through this link [ImportError: cannot import name encodestring from base64](https://github.com/SamLau95/nbinteract/issues/165) as others are also facing this issue even in **pyhton 3.9**

You can also see here [pypi: nbinteract](https://pypi.org/project/nbinteract/) this package have support till **python 3.5**

My suggestion is lower your python version to 3.5 or you can also look an alternative

- [voila](https://pypi.org/project/voila/)
- [streamlit](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit/)
- [dash](https://pypi.org/project/dash/)

These libs have support with latest versions officially till **python 3.10**